# How to check if users owns the object in Firebase bolt compiler

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, firebase-realtime-database

Supposing I have a simple schema with two collections users & posts. Each post object has a key, value pair (ownerId:userId) to find out which users owns the posts object.

```
users/{1,2,3...}
posts/{a,b,c...}/ownerId:userId
```

I am trying to write the rules where user can only read/write his user data and his posts.

For this the bolt rules for the user is quite straightforward:

```
isUser(uid) = auth != null && auth.uid == uid;
path /users/$uid {
    read() = isUser($uid);
    write() = isUser($uid);
}
```

My Question is how can I secure the posts collection to be only accessed by the user. Can I check the ownderId property of the posts collection in rules? If so how, If not they how can I structure my schema to do it?

**EDIT**

I am trying to secure the posts path like this:

```
path /posts/$pid {
  read() = isUser(this.ownerId);
  write() = isUser(this.ownerId);
}
```

Is this the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this by adding a owner Id property to the collection and then checking if the user is authenticated.

```
path /posts/$pid {
  read() = isUser(this.ownerId);
  write() = isUser(this.ownerId);
}
```